# Is there any good reason why one would choose Adobe ColdFusion over Railo?

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I personally can't think of one, but I sincerely want to hear from anyone who thinks Adobe ColdFusion is still worth the money.

Comment: This is a broad question, I think; and likely to bring some bias. One big thing to note here, however, is that Railo seemingly has ceased from any active development since the parting ways of it's key developers. It would appear it's not coming back; at least not any time soon. The bunch that left Railo forked it and started Lucee - http://lucee.org/. I personally use Lucee; though all of the CFML engines have their pros and cons. In regards to "worth the money", I think that all depends on how productive you are. The product should pay for itself if it's built well ;)

Comment: Also, ColdFusion is a commercial product with commercial support, and that has several integrated 3rd party libraries (PDF generation/modification, MS Office document creation/modification, SharePoint and Outlook integrations, LDAP/Active Directory integration, etc.). The quality of these integrations is open to debate. Railo/Lucee are open-source products with mostly community-driven support (there are commercial support plans available for a fee). Railo/Lucee have some extentions available that reproduce some of the 3rd party integrations in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. ColdFusion is a currently actively supported product, and Railo - currently - is not.

However the [Lucee](http://lucee.org/) fork of Railo is seeing active support at the moment, so you should probably at the very least migrate to Lucee.